# Font artifacts on Firefox using fonts googleapis

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I am using google fontapis to get particular font. It looks great on Chrome or Edge, but it has some artifacts on Firefox(check screenshot).
How do I use it in css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa');
body {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif !important;
}
```

The format is WOFF2 which should work good on all browsers.

Any ideas?

[image]